# AWS Cron expression error: "Parameter ScheduleExpression is not valid."

Tags: aws-lambda, cron, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cdk

I am trying to run a lambda 18 pm UTC every Friday:

```
new Rule (this, 'lambda', {
  schedule: Schedule.expression('cron(0 18 ? * FRI *'),
  targets: [lambdaTarget],
})
```

But received error "Parameter ScheduleExpression is not valid."

What is wrong with the expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming it isn't a typo in your question.

```ts
  schedule: Schedule.expression('cron(0 18 ? * FRI *'),
```

should be

```ts
  schedule: Schedule.expression('cron(0 18 ? * FRI *)'),
```

Notice the extra ')'.

Comment: cron(*/60 * * * ? *)

Comment: For me this not working any ideas ?

Comment: @HanojB If you want it to run once every hour, you can add it as `cron(0 * * * ? *)`. This would run at 1:00am, 2:00am, 3:00am, etc.